# Gravity and Larmor effect

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electromagnetism, general-relativity

I have a Q:
Does "Equivalent Principle" and "Larmor effect" imply that the charged particle should radiate electromagnetic wave if it is at rest in uniform gravitational field (like it is at rest on the surface of a massive planet)?

Thanks

Comment: Before introducing gravity, one should first ask "[Does a constantly accelerating charged particle emit em radiation or not?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70915)" in flat spacetime. As you can read there, it is not clear that the Larmor formula even applies, and one has to be **extremely** careful about defining what it means to radiate.