# What is the condition for accelerating charge to radiate?

Tags: electromagnetism, newtonian-gravity, electromagnetic-radiation, acceleration, charge

I was always taught that any accelerating charge produces radiation, but I don't think this condition is sufficient condition. For instance, any free charge on Earth is accelerated due to Earth orbiting the Sun but it doesn't produce radiation.

Comment: "For instance any free charge on Earth is accelerated due to Earth orbiting the Sun but it doesn't produce charge"  did you mean radiation?  I'm sure someone will have an answer for you, but my hunch is that the answer is no because the Earth is following space-time curvature created by the gravitational field of the sun rather than accelerating.

Comment: related:  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70915/ , especially Ben Crowell's answer.

Comment: This article has a pretty good treatment of the subject.  http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath528/kmath528.htm

Answer (score 9):

In fact, an electric charge *at rest* on the Earth's surface is accelerated and this actually poses a challenge to the idea that *uniformly accelerated* charge radiates.  I believe this is still an open question.  For [example](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath528/kmath528.htm):

> One of the most familiar propositions of elementary classical
>   electrodynamics is that "an accelerating charge radiates". In fact,
>   the power (energy per time) of electromagnetic radiation emitted by a
>   charged particle is often said to be strictly a function of the
>   acceleration of that particle. However, if we accept the strong
>   Equivalence Principle (i.e., the equivalence between gravity and
>   acceleration), the simple idea that radiation is a function of
>   acceleration becomes problematic, because in this context an object
>   can be both stationary and accelerating. For example, a charged object
>   at rest on the Earth's surface is stationary, and yet it's also
>   subject to a (gravitational) acceleration of about 9.8 m/sec2. It
>   seems safe to say (and it is evidently a matter of fact) that such an
>   object does not radiate electromagnetic energy, at least from the
>   point of view of co-stationary observers. If it did, we would have a
>   perpetual source of free energy. Since the upward force holding the
>   object in place at the Earth's surface does not act through any
>   distance, the work done by this force is zero. Therefore, no energy is
>   being put into the object, so if the object is radiating
>   electromagnetic energy (and assuming the internal energy of the object
>   remains constant) we have a violation of energy conservation.

A paper [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0506049) proposes that uniformly accelerated charge *does* radiate but that the radiation is "beyond the horizon" for co-moving observers.

> We show, by exploring some elementary consequences of the covariance
>   of Maxwell's equations under general coordinate transformations, that,
>   despite inertial observers can indeed detect electromagnetic radiation
>   emitted from a uniformly accelerated charge, comoving observers will
>   see only a static electric field. This simple analysis can help
>   understanding one of the most celebrated paradoxes of last century.

Comment: so, how far would I need to put the radiation cells from the surface of the Earth to capture the radiation energy from the radiating charges?

Comment: @lurscher, ????

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Is an electron orbiting the sun accelerating?  There is no force being applied.  Alternatively, if an electron were not orbiting, but just held in place by a force, is it not equivalent to acceleration?  In other words an orbiting electron does not radiate, except in an accelerating reference frame?

Comment: @SimpleLikeAnEgg, *any* particle, charged or otherwise, that is not on a geodesic is accelerated, i.e., an accelerometer attached to the particle gives a non-zero reading. *Any* particle in free-fall is inertial, i.e., the accelerometer reads zero.  Does this answer your question?  (it should).

Comment: @AlfredCentauri  Yes: an orbiting particle is on a geodesic and is therefore not accelerating.

Comment: at one-g the Rindler horizon has a radius way smaller than the cosmological horizon, hence I can put cells beyond that distance and capture the radiation from the charges at Earth's surface, and have infinity energy. Don't you see something wrong with that?

Comment: @lurscher, is it not the case that there are no comoving observers beyond the horizon?  And, is it not the case the non-comoving observers detect radiation?

Comment: beyond which horizon? the paper mentions the Rindler horizon only, which is not the same thing as the cosmological horizon

Comment: @lurscher, I haven't mentioned a cosmological horizon anywhere in my previous comments.

Comment: you are right, so if you put a cell outside that horizon, you can capture the radiated energy from the charges on the surface

Comment: @lurscher, I'm not certain why you're focused on a cell outside the horizon.  According to the paper, an *inertial* observer will observe radiation from the uniformly accelerated charge whether inside or outside the horizon.  The paper distinguishes this from co-moving (with the charge) observers which do not observe radiation.  And, as I wrote earlier, there are no co-moving observers outside the horizon.

Comment: If this were to be the case, then you could get radiation energy out of any gravitational well with net charges. I'm not saying that it won't be, but it would be a bit weird. Although if the radiation happened to be thermal, I wonder if one can connect that to a Hawking radiation of charged black holes. Maybe any gravitational body with net charge would tend to evaporate, just like a black hole?

Answer (score -1):

The charge accelerated by the Earth gravity  does not emit any radiation,follows from transforming to a frame of reference in which the charge is stationary and applying relativistic requirement that the behavior of the charge including whether or not it radiates,cannot depend on the frame of reference from which it is viewed.

Comment: That is what is unclear for me (I am not familiar with General relativity). So I can always distinguish between acceleration due to gravity and "normal acceleration"? And what about the Earth orbiting the Sun? Does it produce any radiation (Free charges on Earth)?

Comment: Not really
!my knowledge of our planet is limited,but what I can say is that the Earth hardly or never emits charged  particles,however it does emit radiation in the sense of thermal radiation..if the Earth emitted charged particles,which I am sure would be radioactive,we would be exposed to radiation almost everyday,many creatures would've even been mutated.

Comment: This is simplistic and wrong. There are lots of subtleties involved. For example, it is not necessarily true that the existence of radiation can be defined in a way that is independent of the frame of reference, including noninertial frames.