# Radiation emitted by collision of two photons

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, particle-accelerators

Using Lamor's formula, can someone tell me how much radiation is emitted by a particle accelerator or by the collision of two photons?
It requires a 4 momentum vector which I'm not very acquainted with. Thanks :)

Comment: I assume you are asking for an elaboration / direct calculation of [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/467566/223949) to your previous question?

Comment: I don't think that anyone has ever observed any Delbruck (photon-photon) scattering directly. Certainly not in a terrestrial accelerator.

Comment: Codename 47, haha don't call me out like that but yes. I have to get this project done very soon and I'm struggling with it.

Comment: Photon photon interactions are practically non existent , they have very small probability of  collision, unless very high energy . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon-photon_scattering

Comment: Larmor's formula is a rule for the computation of EM-radiation power of a moving electrical-charged particle, however, photons have no charge, so it cannot be applied. Or do you mean protons ??

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula#Non-covariant_form shows the formula without using four-vectors