# Do accelerated moving electrons radiate electromagnetic energy?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, acceleration

Do accelerated moving electrons radiate electromagnetic energy?

Generally speaking, the charge should absorb energy instead of radiating energy in the acceleration stage, and release energy in the deceleration stage. Acceleration is that charge absorbs external energy into kinetic energy, and deceleration is that kinetic energy is released in the form of electromagnetic radiation.

For example, let's look at X-ray machines. Do electrons radiate in the accelerating phase of an electric field? And look at the electrons in the linear accelerator. Do we need to pay attention to the difference in physics?

In classical electrodynamics, the power radiated by a non-relativistic point charge in vacuum is given by the Larmor formula.
According to Larmor formula, a charge is radiating energy while changing speed. To clarify the difference, simple experiment works. Using electronic fields, let charges be accelerated then decelerated, detect the radiation at the two phases and compare them.

In linear electron accelerator, do the electrons radiate while speeding up? They do radiate while being slowed down(bremsstrahlung).

We do not say bad and disputed word of acceleration or deceleration, just ask do charges release energy while gaining energy?  kinetically or potentially. Electron transition doesn't. It emits photon only when it is releasing potential energy.

In terms of the standard textbook answer, Larmor's formula is derived based on the electric field of an charge in vacuum with acceleration. When the charge is accelerated by an outside electric field, this derivation may not be applicable. Because there is a stronger electric field and interaction with the charge. At least the flux line shown in the derivation is not there or not of that shape, which is changed by the bending of the external electric field. Moreover, this formula is not suitable for charge radiation in atoms.

Comment: There is no "deceleration" in physics. Acceleration is a _vector_ quantity. "Deceleration" is how a lay-person describes the situation when the acceleration of a body points in approximately the opposite direction to its velocity.

Comment: The X generator uses high-speed electrons accelerated by an electric field to bombard large-mass materials. The electrons are slowed down and the original kinetic energy is released.

Comment: Re, "the electrons are slowed down..." My point is, when something slows down, a lay-person might call it "deceleration," but a physicist calls it "acceleration." The only way that the velocity of an object with mass (e.g., an electron) can change, is if a force acts on it. It's the same phenomenon regardless of whether the force acts to speed the object up in some frame of reference or, to slow it down.

Comment: P.S., I am sorry, but I am not qualified to actually answer your question. I do not have a good understanding of the interactions between charged particles (e.g., electrons) and electromagnetic radiation.

Comment: You are qualified. God answer, I got your idea.

Comment: Thanks, but @Puk's answer (below) is an _answer_. Note that it's got an equation in it. Real physics answers usually do because mathematics is the heart and soul of the language that physicists use to describe how the universe works.

Comment: @SolomonSlow One could argue that an adequate definition of deceleration is an acceleration that decreases the speed of the object. Although I agree that the distinction is never really useful in physics.

Comment: @AaronStevens That way lies pedagogical disaster. Students will think that if deceleration leads to decreased speed, acceleration leads to increased speed.

Comment: @G.Smith Acceleration does lead to increased speed, that's just not the only case. Plus I wasn't advocating telling students "Deceleration lowers speed... Ok have a great day!" If this was an actual thing it would just be something to understand about definitions, just like any other definition. I really don't understand the point of your comment or your exaggerated language.

Comment: We do not say bad word of acceleration or deceleration, just ask do charge release energy while gaining energy?  kinetically or potentially. Electron transition doesn't. It only emit photon when it is releasing potential energy.

Comment: @Cang Ye "do charge release energy while gaining energy?" and "In linear electron accelerator, do the electrons radiate while speeding up?" is that the central question ? If yes I suggest to make it more clear in your question as it is lost in a lot of text.

Answer (score 7):

In classical electrodynamics, the power radiated by a non-relativistic point charge in vacuum is given by the [Larmor formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula):

$$ P = \frac{\mu_0 q^2 a^2}{6 \pi c} $$
where $q$ is the charge, $a$ is the magnitude of the acceleration, $\mu_0$ is the permeability of free space and $c$ is the speed of light. Thus the power does not depend on the direction of acceleration, only the magnitude; and an accelerating charge always radiates power regardless of whether it is slowing down ("decelerating"), speeding up, or neither.

Comment: According to Jan Lalinsky this answer is wrong. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70915/does-a-constantly-accelerating-charged-particle-emit-em-radiation-or-not