# Free-falling electron

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, charge, acceleration

An electron freely falls in the Earth's gravity, while being enclosed in a cylinder that contains energy detectors. The electron accelerates and therefore radiates energy, which is detected. However, when viewed from a local inertial (free-falling) frame, the electron is stationary and does not radiate. This paradox has been presented before here, but I find the answers unsatisfying. The detector either registers something or not.

Comment: This question has been answered here before. The electron does not radiate because its field is also accelerated.

Comment: Whether or not you're satisfied with the answer itself, [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/70944) at least includes a good list of references.